# Add data from a reference to another reference

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, vue.js

I'm new with Firebase. I'm looking for a way to push data from a realtime database reference to another reference.

Here is a picture of what I want to do.
[image]

That is to say that, I want to put the record (x) from the Colis Futur reference to the Colis Requetes(D) reference

**Adding data to the reference**`Colis Futur` **No problem at this level. That works**

```
createColis(event){
    const current = new Date();
    const date = current.getFullYear()+'-'+(current.getMonth()+1)+'-'+current.getDate();
    const time = current.getHours() + ":" + current.getMinutes() + ":" + current.getSeconds();
    const dateTime = date +' '+ time;
    const created_at = dateTime;
    const colis = db.ref('Colis Requetes').push({
        client_name: this.cmdColi.client_name,
        client_phone: this.cmdColi.client_phone,
        created_at: created_at,
        montant: Number(this.cmdColi.montant),
        payment_method: this.cmdColi.payment_method,
        agent_id: auth.currentUser.uid
    })
    db.ref('Colis Futur').child(colis.key).child('id_colis').set(colis.key)
    this.$router.push({ path: "/admin/livraison/realtime"});
    event.target.reset();
    event.preventDefault();
},
```

Creation of the function to add data from the `Colis Futur` reference to the `Colis Requetes` reference.
But she doesn't work.

The problem is here:

```
saveColis(key) {
  const snapshot =  db.ref("Colis Futur").child(key).once("value");
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      let childData = childSnapshot.val();
      db.ref("Colis Requetes").set({
        client_name: childData.client_name,
        client_phone: childData.client_phone,
        created_at: childData.created_at,
        montant: Number(childData.montant),
        payment_method: childData.payment_method,
      });
      db.ref("Colis Futur").child(key).remove();
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet you shared uses the Firebase API to write to its [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) database. The second snippet uses the Firebase API to then read from the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), which is also what you're showing a screenshot for. Both Firestore and Realtime Database are part of Firebase, but they are completely separate and data written to the one database cannot then be read from the other.

You'll have to decide which of these two databases you actually want to use, and then stick to *that* API.